# Emmet - how to create multi-line snippets?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, emmet

If I create this code in Emmet.sublime-settings

```
"jqo": "<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>$1"
```

It's works.

But

```
  "bs" : "<link rel='stylesheet' href='1.min.css'>
          <link rel='stylesheet' href='2.min.css'>$1",
```

Or

```
  "bs" : "<link rel='stylesheet' href='1.min.css'> \n <link rel='stylesheet' href='2.min.css'>$1",
```

It does not work

How create multi-line snippet?

Answer (score 0):

See http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/

In your case, you should either create alias:

```
{
    "abbreviations": {
        "bs": "link[href=1.min.css]+[link[href=2.min.css]"
    }
}
```

...or text snippet:

```
{
    "snippet": {
        "bs": "<link rel='stylesheet' href='1.min.css'>\n<link rel='stylesheet' href='2.min.css'>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sergey Chikuyonok is correct, but there's a surplus square bracket in his answer.

This works as expected:

```
{
  "abbreviations": {
    "bs": "link[href=1.min.css]+link[href=2.min.css]"
  }
}
```

But if you need another line break between the two link elements, you can do it like this

```
{
  "abbreviations": {
    "bs": "link[href=1.min.css]+{${newline}}+link[href=2.min.css]"
  }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/285